# Do I need to use the infinitive in a postmodifier?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> *There is no scope to think their life* **easier than before.**

Is the post modifer (easier than before) here used in an appropriate way? Or should I say:

> *There is no scope to think their life* **to be easier than before**

Which one do you think is grammatically correct?

Comment: *none* of them look okay to me. I mean there must be a better way to convince what you want to.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convey? (@MaulikV not convince) Perhaps you could provide some context, because right now it looks like you have translated this literally from your native language.

Comment: *There is no **reason** to think their life **is** [any] easier than before* (or ***will be** easier*, depending on exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say "There is no way in which their lives are easier than before."

You can't use "scope" in this way in English; generally if you wanted to use it in the sense you need you would say "There is no scope for..." but in this case it is not idiomatic:

- "There is no scope for thinking that their lives are easier than before"

It is suitable to use this sort of construction with a noun, or a participle without a subordinate clause; it's more common in business contexts as it sounds quite formal.

- "There is no scope for reductions in the budget."
- "There is no scope for applying new technologies."

Comment: I agree with that sentence you said-
"There is no scope for
thinking that their lives are
easier than before"
but what I've tried to do was just turning that aforesaid sentence into simple instead of the complex form you followed.
Then what is your opinion about making it simple?is it right to say- " There is no scope for thinking their life
easier than before." ?

Comment: No, because it's not "simple" to say that, most native speakers would struggle to understand what you mean; it simply doesn't sound right to omit the verb there although you will find examples where it is appropriate.

Comment: Yes,it's meaning is quite absurd but from my curiosity I wanna minimise the sentence....just say me,is there any grammatical mistake?pls don't think about the meaning now.....

Comment: I don't think there is a formal mistake, but it is unintelligible (impossible to understand) so it is not really English.

Comment: If you want simple, then say, 'There's no way you can think their life is  [lives are ] easier than before."

Comment: Isn't here three finite verb in your sentence('is' & 'can think' & again 'is')  ?
My book says,a simple swntence contains a subject and only one finite verb!!
What do you think about it?

Comment: It's not a "simple sentence" because it contains a subordinate clause.